# How to use multiple commands into Invoke-Command with multiple outputs

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

Currently I have the following `Invoke-Command`:

```cs
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $i -ScriptBlock ${Function:query} `
    -Credential oracle -ArgumentList $metconexao,$dumpdir,$i > $arq
```

Realize that the output of the `Invoke-Command` is put into `$arq` variable.

Now I need to do something like this:

```cs
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $i -ScriptBlock ${Function:query, commandTwo} `
    -Credential oracle -ArgumentList $metconexao,$dumpdir,$i > $arq > outputTwo
```

I need the output of the `commandTwo` in another variable/file.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: @marc_s Please make sure your formatting changes don't break the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a PowerShell session and run each command with a separate `Invoke-Command` statement in the same session:

```
$s = New-PSSession -Computer $i -Credential oracle
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock ${function:query} -ArgumentList $metconexao,$dumpdir,$i > $arq
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { commandTwo } -ArgumentList $metconexao,$dumpdir,$i > outputTwo
```

Note that `> $arq` does not write the output into the *variable* `$arq`, but into a file named after the *value* of that variable.